# as_json dosen't support parameterized methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

While passing methods in 'as_json'/'to_json' to create json response of an object, we cannot pass parameters in methods. What is the reason behind it not being supported in 'as_json/to_json'

For example,

```
@posts.to_json(
:only => [:title, :body, :created_at, :tags, :category],
:methods => [:likes_count, :comments_count])
}
```

Here we cannot pass methods with arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported out of the box, but we can build this.
For Rails 3.2. Add this in `config/initializers/full_json.rb`.

```
module ActiveModel
  module Serializers
    module JSON
      def as_full_json(options = nil)
        root = include_root_in_json
        root = options[:root] if options.try(:key?, :root)
        if root
          root = self.class.model_name.element if root == true
          { root => fully_serializable_hash(options) }
        else
          fully_serializable_hash(options)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

module ActiveModel
  module Serialization
    def fully_serializable_hash(options = nil)
      options ||= {}

      attribute_names = attributes.keys.sort
      if only = options[:only]
        attribute_names &= Array.wrap(only).map(&:to_s)
      elsif except = options[:except]
        attribute_names -= Array.wrap(except).map(&:to_s)
      end

      hash = {}
      attribute_names.each { |n| hash[n] = read_attribute_for_serialization(n) }

      # These two lines do the magic. I check if it's Array, and in case it is, it should accept the arguments.
      method_names = Array.wrap(options[:methods]).select { |n| respond_to?(Array.wrap(n).first) }
      method_names.each { |n| n.is_a?(Array) ? (hash[n.first] = send(*n)) : (hash[n] = send(n)) }

      serializable_add_includes(options) do |association, records, opts|
        hash[association] = if records.is_a?(Enumerable)
                              records.map { |a| a.serializable_hash(opts) }
                            else
                              records.serializable_hash(opts)
                            end
      end

      hash
    end
  end
end
```

Try:

```
# Here method_with_arg is the method which accepts argument. 'arg' is the argument
@posts.as_full_json(
:only => [:title, :body, :created_at, :tags, :category],
:methods => [:likes_count, :comments_count, [:method_with_arg, 'arg']])
}.to_json
```

I'm sure this code can be cleaned and lessened. Possibly by use of alias-chain or something else. You can do it further. Let me know if this works for you.

Cheers

Comment: thanks, i will try this implementation and will let you know if this works for me. But is there any specific reason that you know of for this functionality not being included?

Comment: I think just as an API which converts to JSON, it already has so many options and complexity. I suspect that this wasn't added to prevent more confusion amongst devs.

Comment: do you think an issue should be raised for including this?, because i have seen so many workarounds for this. wouldn't it be a good idea if this is included?

Comment: Good idea. I would love to read more opinions on this in community.